# Why did Kishi draw the One Piece symbol in the last page of the last chapter of Naruto?

Tags: naruto

Why did he put a One Piece skull and crossbones (along with the straw hat) on the very last page of the last chapter of Naruto? Seems odd, as the authors differ in both manga (Kishi - Naruto, Oda - One Piece), and I don't understand why.

[image]

Comment: I really hate that he drew it so big. I get a small hint, but naruto was his own singular work. Many put it above one piece so he should have had a better last scene to finish his manga

Comment: Because ninjas want to be pirates when they grown up.

Comment: Good point @ʞɹɐzǝɹ..:D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oda also made a reference to Naruto in the latest chapter (766):
[image: One Piece 766]
Notice Nami's dress with Konoha's symbol on it, and how there's a fox eating ramen with a whirlpool on its back.

It's just a way for them to acknowledge each other's work.

Comment: Incidentally, we made a post about this on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/AnimeAndMangaQA/posts/373741636126759)

Comment: The title also has three separate references as well. More pertinently, they're friends and long time coworkers.

Comment: the menu items in the background spello out a secret message... in Japanese

Comment: Take note that the I in the One Piece logo is not Luffy but Naruto :P

Plus Konoha symbol for O and a shuriken on the E

Comment: And Naruto is the one eating with Luffy as well

Comment: Also note the characters in the image are ナミ (NAmi), ルフィ (RUfi), and トニートニー・チョッパー (TOni toni choppaa). Take the first kana in each of their names to get ナルト - NARUTO!

Comment: Funny how Naruto is having meat and Luffy is having ramen.

Answer (score 4):

Bolt draw a pirate skull with a hat, a reference to the One Piece series, **part of a wink between authors** of both sleeves on the cover of Chapter 766 of the manga several references appear to Naruto series:

Luffy and back with a fox Uzumaki clan symbol eat ramen and Nami wearing an outfit with the symbol of Konoha, covering with a plate at the same Naruto eating next to Luffy. Besides the logo of the series has been changed and the skull that forms the O has been changed by the leaf symbol, the E has a shuriken, and figure that usually is Monkey D. Luffy (star of One Piece) has been replaced by a silhouette of Naruto.

And yes, it's just a way for them to acknowledge each other's work.

Reference: [Bolt Uzumaki](http://es.naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Bolt_Uzumaki)